# Which JavaScript MVC/Architectural framework solution: Backbone.js vs Dojo Toolkit

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo

I'm trying to choose a solution that give me a good UI architecture. I looked for solutions and the Backbone.js with jQuery is widely spoken.

I suspect the Dojo Toolkit is a high quality and full stack solution, unlike the backbone.js that needs to be combined with other frameworks, but Backbone.js is much talked, because of that I want to hear from the community. I want to know from the community experts has used both and know pros and cons of both.